# Does Ethereum have a list of developer "approved" unofficial wallets with their pros and cons?

Tags: wallets

Bitcoin offers a list of wallets here which is helpful for beginners in deciding what will work best for them (cold storage, web wallet, full node, SPV wallet, etc)
https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Does Ethereum have something similar to help new users decide (preferably written by someone on the development team) which ETH wallet to use?